# TOAD - how to remove rows above data grid

Tags: sql, toad

Is there way to remove these two rows in Toad 17?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

I am the developer who added that "Default" tab.  It it there because in Toad 17.0 you can now pin data grids from different queries.

If I right-click on "Default", I get this.
["Default" tab popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrCdv.png)

After choosing "Pin Data Grid", the data is moved to a new "Pinned" tab, and subsequent query results in the Editor will go into the "Default" tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).